# Function to multiply two matrices in c

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to multiply two matrices in C. Since I have to do the multiplication several times I want to write this as a function and then call it in the main program. Following is the code I have written.

```
//DECLARE THE FUNCTION
#include <stdio.h>
double matMul(int m,int n,int p,int q,double matY[m][n],double matZ[p][q]);
//DECLARE THE VARIABLES NEEDED
int Numstates=3;
double ILX[3][3]= { {1 , 2 , 4} , { 2, 3.5 , 8} , { 1 , 1 , 1 } };
double IADT2A[3][3]={ { 1 , 2 , 4 } , { 2 , 3 , 8 } , { 1 , 1 , 1 } };
double AD[3][3]; int i;int j;double pShow;

int main(){
    //CALLING THE matMul FUNCTION TO MULTIPLY ILX AND IADT2A
    AD=matMul(Numstates,Numstates,Numstates,Numstates,ILX,IADT2A);
    for (i=0;i<Numstates;i++){
        for (j=0;j<Numstates;j++){
            pShow=AD[i][j];
            printf("%lf",pShow);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
//FUNCTION TO MULTIPLY TWO MATRICES
double matMul(int m,int n,int p,int q,double matY[m][n],double matZ[p][q]){
    int count3;int k;int i;int j;
    int colmatYZ=n;
    if (q<n){
        colmatYZ=q;
    }
    double matYZ[m][colmatYZ];
    if (n!=p){

    }
    else{
        for (k=0;k<colmatYZ;k++){
            for(i=0;i<m;i++){
                count3=0;
                for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                    count3=count3+matY[i][j]*matZ[j][k];
                }
                matYZ[i][k]=count3;
            }
        }
    }

    return matYZ[m][colmatYZ];

}
```

Here the "matY" and "matZ" are multiplied and return the product as "matYZ" which is also a 3x3 matrix. And I'm trying to get this product in the main program to the variable "AD".
But it gives me an error saying "incompatible types when assigning to type 'double[3][3]' from type 'double'".
Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here. Thank you!!

Comment: C functions can't return entire arrays. You should instead pass your pre-allocated output matrix `AD` as an argument and make your function return `void`. Since arrays are passed by reference, your function will modify the actual array `AD`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
AD=matMul(Numstates,Numstates,Numstates,Numstates,ILX,IADT2A);
```

`AD` is of type `double [3][3]`, and you're trying to assign the return value of `matMul()`, which is a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the resultant matrix in as a parameter and write to it inside the function. The function prototype will be `void matMul(int m,int n,int p,int q,double matY[m][n],double matZ[p][q]. double matYZ[m][q]);`. The function will be pretty much the same. Just remember to carve out memory for matYZ in the calling function.

Expanded upon the comment by [@eigenchris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3777428/eigenchris).

Comment: How should I return a 2D array?

Comment: The short answer is: don't. If this was python or Java, you could just go `return matYZ`, but in C you have to allocate memory and all that jazz. I suggest doing what someone else suggested in a comment and passing the resultant matrix in as a parameter. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate this.